# finding the wallet address for good ETH showing on Etherscan.io

Tags: wallets, etherscan

I bought ETH from a BTC exchange and it went through ShapeShift. I sent them a wallet address. It has been too long and I don't know the wallet provider I used. The ETH is good on Etherscan. How do I move it to a wallet like MEW? TYIA

Comment: Hi there. Just to confirm - do you have the private key associated with the address, perhaps downloaded from whatever wallet you initially used?

Comment: Yes. I do. The problem is that I believe the exchange was BTC-e. My email at the time was gmail & was deleted by me so I cannot access that account by that email. Waiting for an answer from them.

My private key appears to be for ETC before the split but I assume it will work for both coins.

Reading these forums: do I somehow download Geth to a Mac: and move it into the ethereum wallet from there? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I do. The problem is that I believe the exchange was BTC-e. My email at the time was gmail & was deleted by me so I cannot access that account by that email. Waiting for an answer from them.

My private key appears to be for ETC before the split but I assume it will work for both coins.

Reading these forums: do I somehow download Geth to a Mac: and move it into the ethereum wallet from there? Thanks so much!